# Filter container on column name

Tags: blueprism

Below is `COLLECTION (DATA)` format:

```
Column A    Column B.     Column C
AAAA.       1234.         54
AAAA.       5678.         56
AAAA.       1234.         46
```

I need to loop through the container and sum up `COLUMN C` for matching `COLUMN B`.

The filter container is not working:

```
"[DATA] = COLUMN B"
```

I cannot put the filter condition on text, e.g.:

```
"[DATA] = '2234.'"
```

Also tried without double quotes:

```
[DATA] = COLUMN B
```

Is there a possible way of filtering on column name?

Comment: Why not just use a loop with a calculation stage and sum the column that way?

Comment: Yes ,that way it will work..but just trying to have a efficient solution and make the flow smaller

Comment: It's worked perfectly...thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines of your post, I guess that you're having problems with filtering collection. Example of filtering can be found below:

```
Object: Utility - Collection Manipulation
Action: Filter Collection
Input:
Collection_in: [Data]
Filter: "[Column B.] = '1234'"
```

If you would like to filter collection by a variable, then it's getting a little complicated with all single and double quotation marks and concatenation of strings.

Imagine if the filtering value is stored in data item [Filter].

To filter the collection [Data] by [Filter] data item you need to use following filter:

```
Filter: "[Column B.] = '" & [Filter] & "'"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...think so it will work..will test and provide you feedback